# BLE: Data send by iOS is not able to detect, but working fine with Android

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm using UTF8 encoding to send the simple message to ESP32 BLE device. Device is able to recieve and check the length of the message, but showing as empty while logging. Where as, with android everything working fine.

iOS
`peripheral.writeValue("Hi".data(using: .utf8)!, for: charecterstic, type: .withResponse)`

Android:

```
private void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] data) {
    characteristic.setWriteType(2);
    characteristic.setValue(data);
    gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}
```

I'm unable to figure how else I can send data to peripheral. Is there any other equivalent format for byte[] that was using in Android. I've tried following byte data as well. But this too didn't work.

````
var bytesData = [UInt8] ("Hi".utf8)
let writeData = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &bytesData, count: bytesData.count))
peripheral.writeValue(writeData, for: charecterstic, type: .withResponse)```
````